How to migrate Android Project to Kotlin MultiPlatform Project | Missing Menu
I'm using Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 3.
I am stuck in migrating from android project to kotlin multiplatform.
Based on the JetBrains documentation and several tutorial videos, I found that I should be able to create a Kotlin Multiplatform module by navigating to:
Name (project) → New → Module → Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module.
However, when I follow these steps in my Android Studio, this option is missing. I have already:

Installed the Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin (version [add plugin version]).
Restarted Android Studio to ensure the plugin was properly loaded.

but in my android studio there is no such option? what should i do?
options in my android studio
I have added the required plugins, I hope to migrate even if I use a different way.
